# Великдень, Пасха, Паска

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

На сьогодні в Україні і за її межами не всі розуміють і можуть пояснити: чому головне свято весни має декілька назв – *Великдень, Пасха, Паска*?

Згідно статті у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

> **Вели́кдень, Воскресіння Христове, Паска** (іноді **Пасха**) — найдавніше християнське свято, головне свято богослужебного року, що
>   встановлено на честь Воскресіння Ісуса Христа.

***Чи дійсно ці всі назви можна застосовувати як тотожні одна одній?***

Answer (score 4):

СУМ дає такі визначення:

> **[Паска](http://sum.in.ua/s/paska)** –  1. Солодкий здобний високий білий хліб циліндричної форми, що за православним звичаєм випікається до великодня. *Ґаздиня
>   вже вчиняє паску. Місить тісто з побожними думками, стараючися гнати
>   від себе всяку злість і нечисть* (Гнат Хоткевич, II, 1966, 37).
>    2. Те саме, що великдень.
>
> **[Пасха](http://sum.in.ua/s/paskha)** –  Те саме, що Великдень. *На перші числа травня (десь на 4—5 число) припадав якраз великдень. Отже, міжнародне свято
>   робітничого класу стикалося з.. пасхою* (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957,
>   532).
>
> **[Великдень](http://sum.in.ua/s/velykdenj)** –  Християнське весняне свято, присвячене воскресінню міфічного засновника християнства — Христа. *Не к різдву йде, а к
>   великодню: уночі тріщить, а вдень плющить* (Номис, 1864, № 518)

[Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Па́сха –
>    - 1) (иудейская) па́сха, па́ска;
>    - 2) (христианская) вели́кдень (-кодня);
>    - 3) свяче́на па́ска з си́ру.

Хоча при розмові ці всі терміни плутають, але вони всі різні. Єдина правильна назва найдавнішого християнського свята в українській мові - ***Великдень***. ***Пасха***, те саме що і *Великдень*, проте дану назву використовують іудеї. *Великдень* називають ***"паскою"*** тільки в розмовній мові. Насправді **паска** – солодкий великодній хліб.

Comment: Хм, я завжи вважав, що називати свято _Пас**К**ою_ або страву _пас**Х**ою_ — це груба помилка (що Великдень/Пас**Х**а — це свято, а пас**К**а — це страва). А виявилося он воно як…

Comment: +1. ви дуже швидко вчитесь.

Comment: @P.Vovk намагаюсь, робити все правильно)